# Firebase Permission denied from react app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to save a chess game to firebase. I have a react app and when I use the set() method I get this error:

```
PERMISSION_DENIED: Permission denied
(anonymous function)
C:/Users/Hello/Documents/Dev/chess/src/core/Repo.ts:620
  617 |   let message = code;
  618 |   if (errorReason) message += ': ' + errorReason;
  619 | 
> 620 |   const error = new Error(message);
      | ^  621 |   (error as any).code = code;
  622 |   callback(error);
  623 | }
View compiled
exceptionGuard
C:/Users/Hello/Documents/Dev/chess/src/core/util/util.ts:574
  571 |  */
  572 | export const exceptionGuard = function(fn: () => void) {
  573 |   try {
> 574 |     fn();
  575 |   } catch (e) {
  576 |     // Re-throw exception when it's safe.
  577 |     setTimeout(function() {
View compiled
Repo.callOnCompleteCallback
C:/Users/Hello/Documents/Dev/chess/src/core/Repo.ts:612
  609 |   errorReason?: string | null
  610 | ) {
  611 |   if (callback) {
> 612 |     exceptionGuard(function() {
      | ^  613 |       if (status == 'ok') {
  614 |         callback(null);
  615 |       } else {
View compiled
(anonymous function)
C:/Users/Hello/Documents/Dev/chess/src/core/Repo.ts:342
  339 |       !success
  340 |     );
  341 |     this.eventQueue_.raiseEventsForChangedPath(path, clearEvents);
> 342 |     this.callOnCompleteCallback(onComplete, status, errorReason);
      | ^  343 |   }
  344 | );
  345 | const affectedPath = this.abortTransactions_(path);
View compiled
(anonymous function)
C:/Users/Hello/Documents/Dev/chess/src/core/PersistentConnection.ts:522
  519 |       this.outstandingPuts_ = [];
  520 |     }
  521 | 
> 522 |     if (onComplete)
      | ^  523 |       onComplete(message[/*status*/ 's'], message[/* data */ 'd']);
  524 |   });
  525 | }
View compiled
PersistentConnection.onDataMessage_
C:/Users/Hello/Documents/Dev/chess/src/core/PersistentConnection.ts:554
  551 |   const onResponse = this.requestCBHash_[reqNum];
  552 |   if (onResponse) {
  553 |     delete this.requestCBHash_[reqNum];
> 554 |     onResponse(message[/*body*/ 'b']);
      | ^  555 |   }
  556 | } else if ('error' in message) {
  557 |   throw 'A server-side error has occurred: ' + message['error'];
View compiled
Connection.onDataMessage_
C:/Users/Hello/Documents/Dev/chess/src/realtime/Connection.ts:317
  314 |   this.onPrimaryResponse_();
  315 | 
  316 |   // We don't do anything with data messages, just kick them up a level
> 317 |   this.onMessage_(message);
      | ^  318 | }
  319 | 
  320 | private onPrimaryResponse_() {
View compiled
Connection.onPrimaryMessageReceived_
C:/Users/Hello/Documents/Dev/chess/src/realtime/Connection.ts:309
  306 |   if (layer == 'c') {
  307 |     this.onControl_(data);
  308 |   } else if (layer == 'd') {
> 309 |     this.onDataMessage_(data);
      | ^  310 |   }
  311 | }
  312 | 
View compiled
WebSocketConnection.onMessage
C:/Users/Hello/Documents/Dev/chess/src/realtime/Connection.ts:205
  202 | return (message: object) => {
  203 |   if (this.state_ != RealtimeState.DISCONNECTED) {
  204 |     if (conn === this.rx_) {
> 205 |       this.onPrimaryMessageReceived_(message);
      | ^  206 |     } else if (conn === this.secondaryConn_) {
  207 |       this.onSecondaryMessageReceived_(message);
  208 |     } else {
View compiled
WebSocketConnection.appendFrame_
C:/Users/Hello/Documents/Dev/chess/src/realtime/WebSocketConnection.ts:273
  270 |     const jsonMess = jsonEval(fullMess) as object;
  271 | 
  272 |     //handle the message
> 273 |     this.onMessage(jsonMess);
      | ^  274 |   }
  275 | }
  276 | 
View compiled
WebSocketConnection.handleIncomingFrame
C:/Users/Hello/Documents/Dev/chess/src/realtime/WebSocketConnection.ts:326
  323 |     // try to parse out a frame count, otherwise, assume 1 and process it
  324 |     const remainingData = this.extractFrameCount_(data);
  325 |     if (remainingData !== null) {
> 326 |       this.appendFrame_(remainingData);
      | ^  327 |     }
  328 |   }
  329 | }
View compiled
WebSocket.mySock.onmessage
C:/Users/Hello/Documents/Dev/chess/src/realtime/WebSocketConnection.ts:193
  190 | };
  191 | 
  192 | this.mySock.onmessage = (m: object) => {
> 193 |   this.handleIncomingFrame(m);
      | ^  194 | };
  195 | 
  196 | this.mySock.onerror = (e: any) => {
View compiled
This screen is visible only in development. It will not appear if the app crashes in production.
Open your browser’s developer console to further inspect this error.
```

The error in console:

```
Repo.ts:620 Uncaught (in promise) Error: PERMISSION_DENIED: Permission denied
at Repo.ts:620
at exceptionGuard (util.ts:574)
at Repo.callOnCompleteCallback (Repo.ts:612)
at Repo.ts:342
at PersistentConnection.ts:522
at PersistentConnection.onDataMessage_ (PersistentConnection.ts:554)
at Connection.onDataMessage_ (Connection.ts:317)
at Connection.onPrimaryMessageReceived_ (Connection.ts:309)
at WebSocketConnection.onMessage (Connection.ts:205)
at WebSocketConnection.appendFrame_ (WebSocketConnection.ts:273)
at WebSocketConnection.handleIncomingFrame (WebSocketConnection.ts:326)
at WebSocket.mySock.onmessage (WebSocketConnection.ts:193)
(anonymous) @   Repo.ts:620
exceptionGuard  @   util.ts:574
Repo.callOnCompleteCallback @   Repo.ts:612
(anonymous) @   Repo.ts:342
(anonymous) @   PersistentConnection.ts:522
PersistentConnection.onDataMessage_ @   PersistentConnection.ts:554
Connection.onDataMessage_   @   Connection.ts:317
Connection.onPrimaryMessageReceived_    @   Connection.ts:309
(anonymous) @   Connection.ts:205
WebSocketConnection.appendFrame_    @   WebSocketConnection.ts:273
WebSocketConnection.handleIncomingFrame @   WebSocketConnection.ts:326
mySock.onmessage    @   WebSocketConnection.ts:193
```

I am reading that I need to change the rules to remove authentication for development but that doesn't seem to be working:

[image]

Here's the relevant code in question:

```
import firebase from '../firebase.js';

    const gamesRef = firebase.database().ref('game').push(); //creates node, returns hash id
    const game = {
      pieces:newPieces,
    }
    gamesRef.set(game); // pushes to firebase
```

and my firebase.js:

```
import firebase from 'firebase'
const config = {
    apiKey: "AIzaSyDQKeczO19-gE5Dpvc_NSRkwZWQeasn08o",
    authDomain: "chess-b0d2c.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://chess-b0d2c.firebaseio.com",
    projectId: "chess-b0d2c",
    storageBucket: "chess-b0d2c.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "862405921020",
    appId: "1:862405921020:web:029136c22b33ec84d2af79",
    measurementId: "G-ZXZ50M7GRY"
};
firebase.initializeApp(config);
export default firebase;
```

and yes I did do npm i install firebase. I am not sure what to do at this point. Any suggestions greatly appreciated.

Comment: The second screenshot rules are for realtime database, not firestore. They have different syntax.

Comment: @ Phix I am trying to use the realtime database

Comment: The url in your screenshot denotes that you're configuring firestore, not rtdb.

Answer (score 2):

Ok so I solved it merely by changing the button to "Realtime database" in the top of the top screenshot. That's it. Solved.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This happens due to security reasons provided by Google .
It insert data only if you are sending request from your registered mail id but
in React , you are sending request anonymously that's why it's happen.
To resolve this Go to **Real time database** on left side navbar .

Here , You see an option of Rules on the Top .
Go to Rules and edit it as true for both read and write like this

And Problem resolved .
!!HAPPY CODING !!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).